# How to make latching valve turn to close orientation when power fail when controlling it with H bridge of MOSFETs?

Tags: arduino, transistors, capacitor, h-bridge, latching

I am making a circuit which controls a latching valve this valve is going to be controlled with 2 pins from my MCU. The valve must turn to the close orientation when power fails either from battery or from the MCU. I have done this circuit with relays where the NO and NC makes it easier as when the coil goes off a path is created which I make my 4700 uF discharge in making the valve close but with MOSFETs I can't seem to get it as the capacitor seem to discharge in the source of PMOS but I need also to trigger my transistor responsible of taking the signal from MCU and switch the polarity.
So if anyone had tried this method please help!
[image]

This circuit shows the circuit I followed while making the my connections. Forget about the values as I am just asking about the idea in theory.
Also I have changed the opto-couplers with transistors for now.

Comment: How does the mcu know if the power has failed? Or the H bridge for that matter. The relay seems like a simple solution to me.

Answer (score 0):

1. When power the capacitor can discharge into the power distribution network and the circuits attached to it. A diode in series with the bridge with the capacitor allows the capacitor to discharge into the bridge only.
2. The pmos gates are tied to the nmos gates. This results in a very high shoot-through current during switching that will likely destroy the FETs. Rethink your bridge drivers with a plan for dead time turning off one FET before the other turns on.
3. The MCU must detect the loss of power and respond by closing the valve.